# Why Google Api fonts last-modified keep changing?

Tags: caching, http-headers, google-font-api

When I make a request to a Google Api font (e.g. https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400), the last-modified header is always changing to the current time.

Caching doesn't work as a result and the file has to be downloaded every load. Is there a reason for this? Should I download the file and host it on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I download the file and host it on my server?

Absolutely not, because the content of the CSS files is dynamic and has different content for every user agent. This is because not all browsers support all font formats. Some require WOFF/WOFF2, others require EOT, TTF or SVG. By downloading and serving the file statically you will break font support for all other browsers.

Interestingly though, I do not see a `last-modified` header at all:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/css
Alt-Svc: clear
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Expires: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 09:14:21 GMT
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private, max-age=86400
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 09:14:21 GMT
Content-Length: 222
Connection: close
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

The `Expires` header indeed is the same as the `Date` - so it expires at the time the ressource was loaded. The `max-age` option of `Cache-Control` though has higher precedence. So the file should be cached by the browser for 1 day.